# No confirmation email from Ryanair - how to get a response?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, ryanair

I postponed a Ryanair flight by one week from 2013-01-28 to 2013-02-04 CET. This cost 50 EUR plus price difference, which I can see online on my credit card bill.

However, the Ryanair booking system somehow doesn't seem to have registered the change:

1. I did not get the usual confirmation email (not even in Gmail spam).
2. When I want to view my booking online, by entering my email address and flight data, Ryanair says that they find no information.
3. I still see the old booking (2013-01-28) online.

What can I do? If I call them via their hotline, do I get the money for the call back in case it is their mistake?

Of course, I already used the online form, but so far without reply.

Comment: Whatever you do, document *everything* you do, including getting screenshots of the confirmation showing the wrong date.  If you are unable to resolve the issue, you will be able to use this information to dispute the charges with the credit card company - both for the change as well as for the original ticket price.

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks! Unfortunately, I prematurely closed the browser tab with the confirmation message (and I have history and cache disabled). By the way, I can be certain that the email address is correct, since it is the same that I used for the original booking, which worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I now called Ryanair's telephone support for Germany (+49 900 116 0500, 0.62 EUR / minute). To find my booking, I had to specify my email address, my postal address, and flight data. Support said that, possibly due to a technical glitch, my email address is missing in their system. They then entered the email address, and soon after I received my booking confirmation.

Fortunately, the call only took three minutes or so, and thus was not too expensive. I can live with that.

Comment: I accepted my own answer as it describes the actual solution. I didn't want to give free publicity to a company that gives nothing away for free. That's why I didn't use Twitter for a complaint.

Comment: the call can cost even more: 0.62 EUR/min is the price when you call from landline(Festnetz). If you use mobile phone, it's much more expensive, up to 3 EUR/min and 10 EUR/call

Answer (score 7):

Over the past year, one of the most effective response methods I've found is to tweet the company's twitter account.  Many big companies and certainly several airlines have social media monitoring set up now, and will try to 'take it offline' to prevent public airings of discontent on twitter (no company wants to risk their name trending for a bad reason).

In this case, RyanAir's official twitter account is "[Ryanair](https://twitter.com/Ryanair)".  I'd suggest tweeting them saying that you paid to change your flight, but that it's not showing up, and see if you get a response that way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In fact, in the past I did successfully use Twitter for getting complaints out to companies. However, looking at other tweets, it seems that `@RyanairOfficial` doesn't reply when they are mentioned.